# how update has_and_belongs_to_many table on update activeRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I'm having trouble doing a has_and_belongs_to_many, my data is structured as follows

```
# app/models/student.rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :degree
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services, optional: true  
end
```

```
# app/models/service.rb
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :student, optional: true
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :degree, optional: true
end
```

in my database schema i have this table and the tables of student and service.

```
  create_table "services_students", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "service_id", null: false
    t.integer "student_id", null: false
  end
```

what happens is for a Student to be associated with a Service, I needed to add some lines in services_controller.create()

```
# POST /services or /services.json
  def create
   
    @service = Service.new(service_params)

    for student in params[:service][:student]
      if student != ""
        @service.student << Student.find(student)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save
        format.html { redirect_to service_url(@service), notice: "Service was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

this way the tables save the information correctly. however, in the update() function, when saving the record, the service_students table records are duplicated instead of being updated.

in services_controller i have set the permit params as this:

```
    # service_controller.rb
    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def service_params
      params.require(:service).permit(:student, :vendor_id, :degree_id, :category, :description)
    end
```

and in my form is like this:

```
  # .... begin of form ... 
      <%= form.label :student, "Aluno(s)" %>
      <%= form.collection_check_boxes :student, Student.all, :id, :name do |b| 
        b.label(class:"w-full ") { b.check_box(class:"rounded", checked: @service.student.ids.include?(b.object.id)) + b.text  }

# .... more fields of form ....
```

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong. shouldn't the update function, and even create(), handle this without having to add more code?

I tried to follow some tutorials on the internet, and I realized that the activeRecord should generate the attribute students_ids or students to register the association correctly, but I didn't understand exactly why this happens or why in my model it is referred to as student. (maybe something is wrong)

```
>> rails console
service = Service.find(1) # get the Service with id: 1
student1 = Student.find(1) # get the Student with id: 1
student2 = Student.find(2) # get the Student with id: 2

service.students << student1 # error
service.student << student1 # works 

service.students #error #method missing
service.student # display all students relationship
```

is this supposed to happen?

Comment: in service_controller.rb inside the update function i add the line 
`@service.student.clear` and set the students related to services again. works, but isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assocation should have a plural name:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students # this should be plural! 
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :degree, optional: true
end
```

Use the `students_ids` method generated by `has_and_belongs_to_many :students` with your input:

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :student_ids, Student.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
 <%= b.label(class:"w-full") { b.check_box(class:"rounded") + b.text  } %>
<% end %>
```

And you need to whitelist an array of ids:

```
def service_params
  params.require(:service)
        .permit(
                :vendor_id, :degree_id, 
                :category, :description,
                student_ids: [] # permits an array of values 
             )
end
```

And just get rid of the cruft:

```
  def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: "Service was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The `students_ids=` method which is also created by `has_and_belongs_to_many :students` will automatically add/delete the rows in the join table.

Comment: hey max, thanks for the instructions, i tried to do what you sugest, but something strange happens. 

on rails console, it works fine. 
on application, works fine also, but, the entries of services_students don't get saved as expected.  in methods create and update, the params[:serice][:students_ids] are recived, but nothing is saved target table. 

are we missing something?

Comment: it worked!  i was doing mistakes with studentS_ids and student_ids. i also had to make migrations schema again. Thanks for helping max.

Comment: The pluralization conventions can be hard to remember but is a helpful chart in the API docs which details the methods that are generated from ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html